# How to generate a sitemap.xml from Vue router using Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, sitemap

I'm creating a Webpack configuration for Vue.js from scratch, I want to generate a `sitemap.xml` file dynamically from the Vue router and use [sitemap.js](https://github.com/ekalinin/sitemap.js) to generate the file but I still need the list of routes, I couldn't find a clean way to do this using Webpack, I cannot `require` the Vue router file in my Webpack configuration as it's using ES6 `import` and it's going to throw a `SyntaxError`.

Edit: I have tried using `@babel/register` in my Webpack config file to import the router, but the import is now breaking because of the `.vue` files.

How do you generate a `sitemap.xml` file using Webpack from Vue router?

Comment: I recommend installing an NPM package like vue-router-sitemap.

Comment: @DanyMinassian I've seen that package but it requires the Vue router instance, do you have any examples?

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide what you have done so far, I cannot help you with a very specific answer.
But you can probably solve your problem, by defining your routes as Constants in a different JS file, and then you import the routes to the vue-router file, and also to your webpack conf file to generate the sitemap.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's what I'm currently doing until I find a better solution that doesn't require any code changes, I just wanted to check how others are doing it.

Comment: Is this what you're still doing?

Comment: @Pierre curious to know what solution you found?

Comment: @AaronMcKeehan Sorry I'm no longer using Vue and this Webpack configuration, I remember that I was doing what **Nuxt.js** does, create routes dynamically from a `pages` directory (write a routes file), and I use this data (the file names) to create a sitemap, the solution is ugly, sorry I don't have any code to share right now.
I suggest you just use **Nuxt** / **Gridsome** if you're using **Vue**, or **Gatsby** if you prefer **React**, all of them have sitemap plugins and many more.

Comment: @Pierre thanks, I ended up finding this guide: https://zigamiklic.com/simple-sitemap-for-vue-router/ which is all I needed for a simple website. Though, I'll have to keep Nuxt in mind for bigger sites in the future.